# R: Conditional formatting a column with percentage(%) value

Tags: r, openxlsx

I will need to do color conditional formatting for 1 particular column, format it to percentage, and export the file as .xlsx. Note that I have 5 data frames that I will run this rule code with, and compile them into 1 workbook each in different sheets. I am stuck on the part where I can't seem to set the conditional rule if I formatted the percentage in it. And vice versa, if I conditional format it first, I'm not sure how I can format percentage for that column. Please refer to my code below.

```
## Dataframe
cost_table <- read.table(text = "FRUIT  COST  SUPPLY_RATE
1  APPLE   15   0.026377
2  ORANGE   14  0.01122
3  KIWI   13  0.004122
5  BANANA   11  0.017452
6  AVOCADO   10   0.008324       "  , header = TRUE)

## This is the line where I label the %. However if I do that, conditional formatting will not recognize it in the rule
cost_table$SUPPLY_RATE <- label_percent(accuracy = 0.01)(cost_table$SUPPLY_RATE)

## Creating workbook and sheet
Fruits_Table <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(Fruits_Table,"List 1")

writeData(Fruits_Table,"List 1",cost_table)


## Style color for conditional formatting
posStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#006100", bgFill = "#C6EFCE")
negStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#9C0006", bgFill = "#FFC7CE")

## If Supply rate is above 1.5%, it will be green, if it's equivalent or below, it will be red
conditionalFormatting(Fruits_Table, "List 1",
                      cols = 3,
                      rows = 2:6, rule = "C2> 0.015", style = posStyle
)

conditionalFormatting(Fruits_Table, "List 1",
                      cols = 3,
                      rows = 2:6, rule = "C2<= 0.015", style = negStyle
)
```

The output should be as shown below.

[image: Output]

**Regarding Borderline info**

What I'm looking at is to apply outside border for c2:c6.
[image]

To clarify my purpose, the final output will be shown as below. I have some other codes to format the borders for the headers and column A:B. Because of the percentage style, it affected my borderline.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `label_percent` from `scales` package.
You can apply the percentage format along with the color rules to the workbook by using `style` and then `addStyle` functions. Another thing, I found in the documented examples of `conditionalFormatting` that you don't need to specify the column name (such as `C`) in the `rule` argument if your rule apply to only one column with no relation to values in another column.

Here is the code that I used:

```
Fruits_Table <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(Fruits_Table,"List 1")
writeData(Fruits_Table,"List 1",cost_table)
conditionalFormatting(Fruits_Table, "List 1",
                      cols = 3,
                      rows = 2:6, rule = "> 0.015", style = posStyle) 
conditionalFormatting(Fruits_Table, "List 1",
                       cols = 3,
                        rows = 2:6, rule = "<= 0.015", 
                       style = negStyle)
percent_style <- createStyle(numFmt = "PERCENTAGE")
addStyle(Fruits_Table,"List 1", style = ,percent_style, rows = 2:6, cols = 3)
```

I tried that code and it works.

```
saveWorkbook(Fruits_Table, "my_fruits_table.xlsx", )
```

[image]

**Updated to add borderline info**

In case you want to create borderline along with the percentage format, you can use `border` and `borderStyle` as follows:

```
percent_border_style<- createStyle(numFmt = "PERCENTAGE", 
                       border = "TopBottomLeftRight", 
                       borderStyle = "medium" )

addStyle(Fruits_Table,"List 1", 
        style = ,percent_border_style, 
        rows = 2:6, cols = 3)

saveWorkbook(Fruits_Table, "borderline_fruits_table.xlsx", )
```

Here is the borderline result

[image]

In case you want to customize different styles to different cells, as you explained in your comment, you need to `createStyle` for a particular style, and then you use `addStyle` to apply that particular style to a particular cell. So, you need to specify the row and the column for each style. To keep the percentage format style, you also need to keep `numFmt` to each `addStyle`.

Here is an example code to apply outside borders to the targeted column. The code customizes borders to three groups of cells:

```
top_side_line <- createStyle(numFmt = "PERCENTAGE", 
                             border = "TopLeftRight", 
                             borderStyle = "medium")
side_line <- createStyle(numFmt = "PERCENTAGE", 
                             border = "LeftRight", 
                             borderStyle = "medium")
bottom_side_line <- createStyle(numFmt = "PERCENTAGE", 
                             border = "BottomLeftRight", 
                             borderStyle = "medium")
addStyle(Fruits_Table,"List 1", 
         style = top_side_line, rows = 2, cols = 3)
addStyle(Fruits_Table,"List 1", 
         style = side_line, rows = 3:5, cols = 3)
addStyle(Fruits_Table,"List 1", 
         style = bottom_side_line, rows = 6, cols = 3)
saveWorkbook(Fruits_Table, "newline_fruits_table.xlsx")
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Rohman. Thank you for this. Your solution works. Can I also check with you how can I add border lines to it as well? I tried to run another addStyle but it will overwrite it the percentage style. I only need the border lines surrounding  each column from rows 2:6

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: More detailed info is available in `?openxlsx::createStyle`

Comment: Hi Rohman. Yes I tried applying that condition but the border applies to all the cells. I will require only the outside borders. I have updated my question with the screenshot.

Comment: It's relatively easy to get that. Please check my updates.